# Why I am I getting an 'Illegal characters in path' exception from WCF service call?

Tags: wcf

I am currently adding a new function to an existing WCF service. The function returns a DataSet which is the result of a call to a stored procedure.

There is an existing function similar to this which I know works so I duplicated the setup in the ServiceContract and the code that implements the contract.

I can call the function using the WCFTestClient and when debugging I can step through each line in the function without error and see the DataSet object i'm returning has the data I expected.

The problem is after the function has completed I get an exception stating that there are illegal characters in the path?

I have no idea why this is, it appears as though the XML being generated as a response contains errors, but I'm not sure why that would be? There are no unusual characters in the data returned.

I've turned on logging, but this doesn't reveal anything obvious. Does anyone know why this might be happening or could recommend further steps to debugging

TIA

Comment: Because `DataSets` consists `DataTable(s)` which is not serializable!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply vendettamit. Are you saying returning a DataSet object isn't possible?

Comment: The return type of wcf service operations should be serializable. AFAIK datatables are not serializable. You should create a entity class that matches the schema and retune the list of the enity class. That should work.

Comment: Datasets can be serialized bt its a heavy object for serialization. List<T> is a way to go.

Comment: I did think it was possible. I do understand it's not best practice for the reason you've described. Unfortunately that's what I've been asked to do, so I guess I'll have to dig a bit deeper. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was getting no where with this so I decided to write my own test client, and guess what? IT ALL WORKED FINE!

I knew the test client struggled with objects, but didn't realise it would throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error "Illegal characters in path" when trying to invoke some service from the WcfTestClient.exe. Turned out, in my case, the problem was that I was using a copy of WcfTestClient.exe (I had copied the .exe in a location where I keep other shortcuts, for convenience). I then created a proper shortcut to the WcfTestClient.exe and that worked without error.